# Jquery - Bootstrap DataTable Refresh issue DATA

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Could you please assist me with this issue related to Bootstrap - Jquery Table?

I would like to retrieve data from a database server In JSON Format (through an ajax call) into a bootstrap DataTable and then reload the DataTable only.

Here you are the code, this will be run once pressed the click button (search):

```
var prova = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
        prova = $('#prova_table').DataTable({
            paging: true,
            searching: false
        });
        prendivalori();
       });  


function prendivalori() {
       $("#bottone").click(function() {
        $("#prova_table").empty();
        var sopravvissuti = $('#sopravvissuti').val();
        var vita = $('#vita').val();
        var provincia = $('#provincia').val();
        var campi = $('#campi').val();
        var table = $('#prova_table');

        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: './php/select.php',
                data: {'sopravvissuti': sopravvissuti, 'vita': vita, 'provincia':provincia, 'campi':campi},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                                    table.append("<thead><tr><th class='th-sm'>Cognome</th><th class='th-sm'>Nome</th><th class='th-sm'>Sesso</th></tr></thead>");
                                    console.log(data);
                                    len=data[0].length;
                                    table.append("<tbody>");
                        for(i=0; i< len; i++){

                            temp=data[0][i]
                            table.append("<tr><td>" + temp[1] + "</td><td>" + temp[0] + "</td><td>" 
                            + temp[2] +"</td></tr>");
                        }
                                                table.append("</tbody>");

                                                $('#prova_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();

                        }

                ,
                error: function(data) {
                        alert('Assicurarsi di aver selezionato tutte le caselle');

                }
        });

    });
};
```

Here you are the error message received once clicked button data...

DataTables warning: table id=prova_table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

The json data received from the server are correct because we can see them properly into the table but we are unable to use all the functions Bootstrap DataTable provides like **Pagination** **search** and **number of entries**....

I'm using all the updated links for running the website ..

ETC ECT

Here you are a JSON response:

[image: JSON Response]

Many thanks in advance for all you kind support
Have a nice day
Andrea

Comment: Could you mimic the json response here https://www.mocky.io/ and share the link? or add it in the question itself?

Comment: @supercool, yes! added a screenshot from Chrome console... I hope it can helps :)

Comment: send array of objects (each object should have keys as column names and value as values) from backend not array of arrays. and also in success function you need not do table.append and other stuff like that . if you are receiving the data in correct format mentioned  above then just use $("yourtableid").DataTable({data:response});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do table.append() and any other direct dom changes on table.
Jquery data table will do this for you if you pass options to it in right way.

Do it this way.

First initialize the datatable like below with column names if available

```
var table = $("#myTable").DataTable({
    data:[],
    columns: [
                { "data": "Cognome"  },
                { "data": "Nome" },
                { "data": "Sesso" },
                { "data": "data di nascita" }
    ],        
});
```

in on click of button, do a get ajax call and in done callback clear the table `table.clear().draw();` and `table.rows.add(result).draw()` to render data to the table.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5e89289e3100005600d39c17",
            type: "get",
        }).done(function (result) {
            table.clear().draw();
            table.rows.add(result).draw();
         })
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k0d1mzgL/

```js
var table = $("#myTable").DataTable({
    data:[],
    columns: [
           { "data": "Cognome" ,"title": "Cognome"},
{ "data": "Nome" ,"title": "Nome"},
{ "data": "Sesso" ,"title": "Sesso"},
{ "data": "data di nascita","title": "data di nascita" }
    ],        
});
$("#getDataBtn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5e89289e3100005600d39c17",
            type: "get",
        }).done(function (result) {
            table.clear().draw();
            table.rows.add(result).draw();
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
               //if failed
               console.log("Due to https issue,this request cant be made, go check jsfiddle link provided in answer");
            });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">

</table>
<button id="getDataBtn">Get data</button>
```

Comment: @sn4k did you check my solution?

Comment: Hello Supercool, yeah, I've finished right now to adapt the code :) MANY THANKS FOR your GREAT SUPPORT!! :)